# Checking if a page is up prior to loading the page

Tags: javascript

We need a solution to the following issue.

We currently refresh a screen every 30 seconds, what we need to do prior to the actual refresh is check if the website is still up and if there is a network present to access the page.

If the page is down then we delay the refresh by 6 seconds this is repeated 5 times.

If the fifth attempt is showing that the website is still down then an error message is displayed.

This is working fine but we need to check if the website is still available (ping the website prior to refreshing) and also we need a solution if the browser starts to refresh but loses the connection or the server goes down once the refresh has started

This is the current code

```
window.onload = function () {
    var refresh_rate = 30; //<-- Second until refresh
    var connection_attempts=5;  ////// Connection attempts
    var failed_seconds=6;
    var inactivity_counter = 0;
    var connection_failed= 0;

    function reset1() {
        inactivity_counter = 0;
        console.log("Reset1");
    }

    function reset2() {
        inactivity_counter = 0;
        console.log("Reset2");
    }

    function reset3() {
        inactivity_counter = 0;
        connection_failed = 0;
        console.log("Reset3");
    }

    function reset_network() {
        inactivity_counter = (refresh_rate - failed_seconds);
        console.log("ResetNetwork");
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        inactivity_counter++;
        refreshCheck();
    }, 1000);

    function can_i_refresh() {
        if (inactivity_counter >= refresh_rate) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function refreshCheck() {
        if (can_i_refresh()) {
            if(navigator.onLine) {
                connection_failed='0';
                window.location.href='alreadybooked.php?location=5';
                inactivity_counter = 0;
            }
            else {
                connection_failed++;
                console.log(connection_failed);
                if(connection_failed==connection_attempts) {
                    alert("Error 1001: This check-in device is currently experiencing issues. Please check-in on another device. If you still experience issues, please press the 'OK' button and proceed to reception");
                    return false;
                }
                reset_network(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(inactivity_counter);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("click", reset1);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", reset2);
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to ask a specific question not ask for a solution.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What is the current code trying to do and failing? What have you tried so far? This is a vague and hard to answer question

Comment: what we need to know is which function can we use that will allow us to ping our server to check if it is still up and what can we do to capture if the refresh has started but the website goes down whilst the browser is being refreshed.

Comment: If at all possible, you should use AJAX (including CORS, if necessary) - with that you have the part of "did the website respond with any data that can be displayed" already built in, and don't need an extra request.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

The function `setupPageReload()` creates a timeout so that the page reload will start after the specified delay.  The actual reload is done into a temporary element, so the check for availability and the reload are the same thing.  If the reload doesn't happen (for any reason) then the fail counter is incremented and will execute the `fatalError()` function if there have been enough retries.  If it works then it simply replaces the contents of the current page with the contents that were just downloaded.  Unless there was a "fatal error" then the function is simply executed again to start the process all over.

```
var refreshRate = 30;
var connectionAttempts = 5;
var connectionFailed = 0;

function setupPageReload() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("<div/>").load(location.href + " body", function(response, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                connectionFailed = 0;
                $("body").html(response);
                setupPageReload();
            }
            else {
                if (++connectionFailed === connectionAttempts) {
                    fatalError();
                }
                else {
                    setupPageReload();
                }
            }
        });
    }, refreshRate * 1000);
}

function fatalError() {
    alert("Error 1001: This check-in device is currently experiencing issues. " +
        "Please check-in on another device. If you still experience issues, " +
        "please press the 'OK' button and proceed to reception");
}

window.onload = setupPageReload;
```

Incidentally, this method requires jQuery as that performs the ajax download and gets the content of the `<body/>` tag much, much easier than if you were to do that in vanilla js.  If you don't already use that in the page in question then you'll need to add a script include.

Comment: Thanks Archer, this is the part we are not sure of. If the page has started the refresh how can we capture if the page has loaded?

Comment: Without seeing your refresh code there's no way to answer that.  I assume there's a function that performs the refresh - that function needs to indicate success and/or failure, so maybe a callback method (like I used above) would be suitable.

Comment: When the check is complete the following code is run

Comment: technically not a refresh

Comment: You can't handle that - it will work or won't work, just like it would if you visited that url by typing it in the address bar of a browser and hitting enter.  If you're worried about the page check method firing after you set `window.location.href` then don't - it will just be destroyed when the new version of the page loads.  Alternatively, set a global flag before you execute the page reload and have the check page function immediately exit if that flag is set.  Unnecessary, but will do what you ask.

Comment: is there any other solution we could use that would do what we are trying to achieve?

Comment: Difficult to answer without details.  Are you only wanting to refresh one part of the page, like a table, for instance?

Comment: the page is used on a screen that is on 24 hours a day, the problem is if the refresh is done and the network is lost/server is down then browser would show a "network lost"  browser error.   it would require a refresh by an actual user to get the page back online. this is why we are checking to see if the website is still up prior to the refresh and delaying if it is

Comment: delaying if its down

Comment: If that's the case then it's very simple and you've overcooked it.  I can give you an example.  Would it need to show an error, or do you want it to just keep trying in the background, if it's failing, and then eventually update again when it can?

Comment: Do you need to completely reload the whole page, or just part of it?

Comment: we would want to display an error message after 5 trys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126245/discussion-between-chris-campbell-and-archer).

Comment: I'll give you an example of how I'd do what you're proposing - we can chat after that, if needed.

Comment: Try the code I've just added - that should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, very much appreciated. the key part which we need to confirm is that if a refresh is initiated and then connection is lost will we be able to stop the refresh and not display a browser error message "no internet connection" or "cannot find page"

Comment: The page check no longer exists with this proposed solution.  The page check *is* the refresh.

Comment: Currently the window.onload = reloadPage; is returning an alreadybooked.php?location=3:56 Uncaught ReferenceError: reloadPage is not defined

Comment: Sorry - that was an early name for the function that I later changed to actually reflect what it's doing.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: Hi Archer, amazingly after getting this to work perfect it turns out that .load does not work on ipad which has caused huge issues. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Apple products are worse than IE for doing what they want regardless of standards, I'm afraid to say.  Try changing `location.href` to `window.location.href` in the load call.  If that doesn't help then you'll need to just debug it and find out what's going on on that device.